# How to set cookie at user authentication in Django ?

Tags: django, cookies, request

Hey, can someone help me to set this cookie in django ;s Here is the code ;p

```
class MFAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username and password:
        self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    self.request.set_cookie("mfusername", username)
        if self.user_cache is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive."))
        elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This account is not yet active."))
        elif self.user_cache.penalty > 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("For unfair treatment of the conditions of the site, MacroFactor has removed your account. To use the services of MacroFactor you need to register again. In subsequent registration please stick to the established rules. "))

    # TODO: determine whether this should move to its own method.
    if self.request:
        if not self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Your Web browser doesn't appear to have cookies enabled. Cookies are required for logging in."))

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981601/django-use-render-to-response-and-set-cookie, it might help

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it in the login view:

```
username = ''

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']

response = render_to_response(...)
# if you are using redirect, 
# response = redirect(...)

if username:
    response.set_cookie("mfusername", username)

return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the cookie in the response, not the request.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie

You should se t the cookie wherever you are building the response (typically your view)

Comment: If i can i will do it mah man, but im asking for help becuz im cycling on this 2 days ..