# Django: use render_to_response and set cookie

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Currently, I'm using `render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context-etc..)`

Trying to set a cookie right now and I'm wondering if I can do it with `render_to_response`.

All the examples I see are using `HttpResponse` object. They set the cookie in the response object, like this

```
response = HttpResponseObject(html)
response.set_cookie("favorite_color",request.GET["favorite_color"])
return response
```

Wondering if I can set cookie with `render_to_response`, so I can continue using locals()

Thank you.
David.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, not a problem. The principle is exactly the same.

```
response = render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context-etc..)
response.set_cookie("favorite_color",request.GET["favorite_color"])
return response
```

Comment: this will render the page and set the cookie so for the first run "favorite_color" may not be there.