# unable to output cookie value in django

Tags: django

My view.py

```
def search(request):
    res = HttpResponse('Setting Response');
    res.set_cookie("name","abcd")
    return render_to_response("search.html", {"res":res})
```

My search.html

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>{{res.COOKIES.name}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Even `{{request.COOKIES.name}}` is also not working. I am unable to get value `"abcd"` it is giving `" "` (empty string)

Please help me in this regard

Comment: This is nonsense. Why would you pass an HttpResponse into a template?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
...
return render(request, "search.html", {"res":res})
```

so the request instance will be available on the template

**UPDATE:**

If your goal is to set a cookie and then retrieve it on a template you can do next:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def search(request):
    response = render(request, "search.html")
    # render function returns a HttpResponse object
    response.set_cookie("name","abcd")
    return response
```

Then on a template:

> {{ request.COOKIES.name }}

Solution came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981601/django-use-render-to-response-and-set-cookie)

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to set some cookie parameter on a view.py and then retrieve it on a template?

Comment: my goal is to set a cookie in view.py and retrieve it in a .html file using template

Answer (score 1):

request variable is not automatically available to your views.

```
return render_to_response("search.html", {"request":request})
```

Comment: Thank u  but this way also its not working I am unable to get my desired value

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get cookie in the view and pass in the template or pass `request` variable to the template.

Another way is to enable [request context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) so that `request` variable is available by default in the template.